# TimePicker's time does not get updated after setCurrentHour/Minute() correctly

Tags: android, android-preferences, timepicker

I am extending a DialogPreference to get the following Dialog:

[image: The dialog wanted]

I want it to be able to pick two times: a starting time and an ending time (for whatever reason). For this the TimePicker should always show the time on the ToggleButton that is checked.

In order to let the user know which of both times he is currently changing, I use ToggleButtons and ensure by OnCheckedChangeListeners that exactly one is checked all the time. No problems so far. The same listeners are used to change the text on those ToggleButtons (by both, the setTextOn/setTextOff, methods).

See the following code I use in the extended DialogPreference:

```
/*
* Bind data to our content views
* */
@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    super.onBindDialogView(view);

    // use 24h format
    mTimePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

    mToggleButtonFrom = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonDisplayOnFrom);
    mToggleButtonUntil = (ToggleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.toggleButtonDisplayOnUntil);

    // save the time of the timepicker internally for both buttons, if there are no saved values
    if(fromHour == -1 && fromMin == -1) {
        fromHour = mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
        fromMin = mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
    }
    if(untilMin == -1 && untilHour == -1){
        untilHour = mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
        untilMin = mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
    }

    // set currently saved times
    mToggleButtonFrom.setTextOn(String.format("%02d", fromHour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", fromMin));
    mToggleButtonFrom.setTextOff(String.format("%02d", fromHour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", fromMin));
    mToggleButtonUntil.setTextOn(String.format("%02d", untilHour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", untilMin));
    mToggleButtonUntil.setTextOff(String.format("%02d", untilHour) + ":" + String.format("%02d", untilMin));

    // update the button (not working without this)
    mToggleButtonFrom.setChecked(mToggleButtonFrom.isChecked());
    mToggleButtonUntil.setChecked(mToggleButtonUntil.isChecked());

    // set togglebuttons to exclude each other
    mToggleButtonFrom.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
                if (mToggleButtonUntil.isChecked())
                    mToggleButtonUntil.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
                if (!mToggleButtonUntil.isChecked())
                    mToggleButtonUntil.setChecked(true);
                fromHour = getCurrentlyPickedHour2();
                fromMin = getCurrentlyPickedMinute2();
                String time = getStringTime(fromHour, fromMin);
                mToggleButtonFrom.setTextOff(time);
                mToggleButtonFrom.setTextOn(time);
                setTimeToTimePickerSlim(false);
            }
        }
    });

    mToggleButtonUntil.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The toggle is enabled
                if (mToggleButtonFrom.isChecked())
                    mToggleButtonFrom.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                // The toggle is disabled
                if (!mToggleButtonFrom.isChecked())
                    mToggleButtonFrom.setChecked(true);
                untilHour = getCurrentlyPickedHour2();
                untilMin = getCurrentlyPickedMinute2();
                String time = getStringTime(untilHour, untilMin);
                mToggleButtonUntil.setTextOff(time);
                mToggleButtonUntil.setTextOn(time);
                setTimeToTimePickerSlim(true);
            }
        }
    });

}

private void setTimeToTimePickerSlim(boolean from){
    if(from){
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(Integer.valueOf(fromHour));
        mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(Integer.valueOf(fromMin));
    } else {
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(Integer.valueOf(untilHour));
        mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(Integer.valueOf(untilMin));
    }
}

private int fromHour = -1;
private int fromMin = -1;
private int untilHour = -1;
private int untilMin = -1;

private int getCurrentlyPickedHour2(){
    return mTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
}

private int getCurrentlyPickedMinute2(){
    return mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
}

private String getStringTime(int hour, int min){
    return String.format("%02d", hour)+":"+String.format("%02d", min);
}
```

I have absolutly no clue, why the TimePicker is not updating to the shown (and set) time, when I choose a new time and then click on one of those ToggleButtons (same behaviour for both of them as far as I can tell).

But the most interesting part comes now: When I do this twice (choose a new time, toggle the buttons, choose another time, toggle again), the TimePicker starts toggling the shown time, too. Exactly what I want it to show!

I tried a lot of things, here are my 'best' guesses:

If I change the method setTimeToTimePickerSlim(boolean) to

```
    private void setTimeToTimePickerSlim(boolean from){
    if(from){
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(3);
        mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(15);
    } else {
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(21);
        mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(45);
    }
}
```

this works like intended (but is of cause a bit to static to be usefull ..). Unfortunately removing the Integer.valueOf() does not help, too.

I would be very happy for any hint (since I am trying to debug this for hours now).

**Update:** I logged the values by the following modification

```
 private void setTimeToTimePickerSlim(boolean from){
    Log.i("StrangeBugTest", "Before setting: from: " + fromHour + ":" + fromMin + "   until: " + untilHour + ":" + untilMin + "   (from=" + from + ")");
    Log.i("StrangeBugTest", "Pickertime: " + mTimePicker.getCurrentHour() + ":" + mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
    if(from){
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(fromHour);
        mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(fromMin);
    } else {
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(untilHour);
        mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(untilMin);
    }
    Log.i("StrangeBugTest", "After setting: from: " + fromHour + ":" + fromMin + "   until: " + untilHour + ":" + untilMin + "   (from=" + from + ")");
    Log.i("StrangeBugTest", "Pickertime: " + mTimePicker.getCurrentHour() + ":" + mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
}
```

When I start the app (and open the preferenceDialog) I get the following screen:

[image: on start]

I than picked the hour 21 (because I am using 24h-format) and minute 45. After this i clicked the toggleButtonFrom (on the left). This gets me the following log (shortened):

- 10-20 19:43:11.575  Before setting: from: 21:45   until: 19:42   (from=false)
- 10-20 19:43:11.575  Pickertime: 21:45
- 10-20 19:43:11.575  After setting: from: 21:45   until: 19:42   (from=false)
- 10-20 19:43:11.575  Pickertime: 21:45

This is wrong, because the pickertime should be 19:42 after the setting. However, the gui is consistent to the picked time:

[image: after first toggle]

I than changed the Picker back to hour, chose hour 15 followed by minute 15 and clicked on ToggleButtonUntil (right one). This gives me the following log

- 10-20 19:44:26.178  Before setting: from: 21:45   until: 15:15   (from=true)
- 10-20 19:44:26.178  Pickertime: 15:15
- 10-20 19:44:26.188  After setting: from: 21:45   until: 15:15   (from=true)
- 10-20 19:44:26.188  Pickertime: 21:45

This is how it should work from the very beginning! The GUI shows:

[image: after second toggle]

From here on, everything is fine, both, times and buttons toggle as intended. But I do not see, why the first one does not work. I would be happy for every hint I can get.

Comment: can you log the value of `fromHour`, `fromMin` , `untilHour` and `untilMin` whenever  `setTimeToTimePickerSlim` is called. My guess is that in your listeners you are not setting the value of these properly because listeners are getting called not the way you intend them to.

Comment: Also initially in `onBindDialogView` which one of the buttons is checked. I don't see you setting one button in `checked` state and other in `unchecked` state. If initially both the button are in `unchecked` state then we have a problem

Comment: I will edit a log into the question once I am back at my computer. The toggleButtons checked-state are set in the xml of the layout. Initially mToggleButtonFrom is checked and mToggleButtonUntil is not, so there should not be a problem with this.

Comment: @pgiitu See the updated question - strang behaviour, isnt it?

Comment: @Dominikus K., did you find any reason? I am facing the similar problem but unable to solve it out. Would you be able to help?

Comment: @Deepti, unfortunately I did not. I am now using two timepickers (with `android:timePickerMode="spinner"` to save space) simultaneous without any togglebutton. For me that works quite good (even easier to understand for the users). I would have posted an answer if I found a reason (and would be happy to check yours, when you find one)!